# add a handle to curve

Tags: bezier-curves

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXldgzeuj1k) tutorial, Ian adds another vert onto his curve making now 3 adjusting handles. How do I add another handle?

Answer (score 1):

(In 2.8) select the 2 control points at the ends of the segment of interest, Right-Click > 'Subdivide'